# Return an OCR'd PDF File (with text overlay) from Azure Cognitive Services Read

Tags: ocr, azure-cognitive-services

I have implemented Azure Cognitive Read service to return extracted/OCR text from a PDF.

However, to make it easier for the user to understand the context/copy and paste data from the PDF i would like to overlay that text data over the PDF. I would then drop that PDF into a viewer.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to proceed. Would also be happy to use AWS. Basically an API that i submit a PDF to and it returns an OCR'd PDF is what i am after. If this is not possible, a library that i can submit the text and the PDF (and return a text searchable PDF) is also ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for something similar and stumbled upon this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/overview?tabs=v2-1

This is the Azure form recogniser.

**What is Azure Form Recognizer?**

Azure Form Recognizer is a part of Azure Applied AI Services that lets you build automated data processing software using machine learning technology. Identify and extract text, key/value pairs, selection marks, tables, and structure from your documents—the service outputs structured data that includes the relationships in the original file, bounding boxes, confidence and more. You quickly get accurate results that are tailored to your specific content without heavy manual intervention or extensive data science expertise. Use Form Recognizer to automate data entry in your applications and enrich your documents search capabilities.

They have an online example test:
https://fott-2-1.azurewebsites.net/prebuilts-analyze

Create a service in azure for free and test if it fits your needs. From there you will get a json reply and you can use the boundingBox to display. I haven't gone as far as applying the bounding box or something like that to the pdf.

You also have a free development nuget package to do exactly as you want:

https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/#sample-tesseract-create-searchable-pdf

OCR development is free for testing and see if it works for you.